# Why does the build fail with unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;0.7.4?

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

According to [Typesafe Activator](https://typesafe.com/activator), I am using sbt launcher version 0.13.5.

I get the following error when attempting to run `./activator run` on code that I've inherited, which works on another machine.

```
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;0.7.4
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\<username>\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.sbt\sbt-native-packager\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\0.7.4\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-releases-repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugins-repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== maven-central: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-native-packager_2.10_0.13/0.7.4/sbt-native-packager-0.7.4.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-native-packager_2.10_0.13/0.7.4/sbt-native-packager-0.7.4.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;0.7.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:0.7.4 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;0.7.4: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:103)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:48)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:57)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:94)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:115)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:125)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1223)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1221)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1244)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1242)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1246)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1241)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1249)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1214)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1192)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;0.7.4: not found
```

I don't understand the module that it's looking for, which does not appear in any of the `build.sbt` or `plugins.sbt` files.

Comment: What's strange is that while some of the repos that sbt tries do have the dependency, but there's no version 7.4 (only 7.0 and 8.0). I can't tell where this dependency is from.

Comment: This issue should be resolved now. It was caused by an error during a server upgrade.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is another workaround to the problem:

Add the bintray repo to your resolvers (project/plugins.sbt).

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Comment: Oops, didn't see your answer there!

Answer (score 2):

I was just running into the same problem. I think somebody bilged a release, but I'm not sure.

As a workaround, you can copy a jar and call it 0.7.4 in your local repository. I don't suggest it for more than a temporary thing, of course, but it can get you running. (This is what I did.)

Comment: Yeah, I seem to be getting somewhere by copying the Ivy cache from my boss's computer into mine (slightly restructuring to fit the program's expectations). Still compiling, but it's got rid of the original error.

Answer (score 2):

It has been already fixed redirecting http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/ to http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/ .
Not sure if it is a temporal or definitive workaround, but now it works now as before.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hopefully temporary issue, caused by a problem with mirroring the Bintray repository. Peter Vlugter has [posted](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/zaOsiUNJaiY/ot9wIdgdONkJ) a workaround:

> As a workaround for now, add the bintray repository to `project/plugins.sbt`:
>
> ```
> resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
> ```